# Do consecutive PVP wins make you glow a brighter red?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I'm almost positive that I read somewhere (and can no longer find it) that if you go on a win streak as a brotherhood of blood member, you're red aura glows a brighter red?

Anyone confirm/deny?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the Dark Souls 2 Wiki](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Brotherhood+of+Blood) you will gain the 'brighter' glowing aura at Rank 2 (R2).

- **R1**: Player gets a red aura surrounding the player
- **R2**: Player has the aura as well as you are notably more of a "bright
  neon" red.
- **R3**: Player does not receive any extra aesthetics to your aura.

Rank requirements:

- **R1**: 50 RP
- **R2**: 150 RP
- **R3**: 500 RP

Clarifications/Notes:

- RP (rank points) are earned and lost.  You gain one for a win, lose one for a loss.

  - Example: Player invades 100 worlds.  Wins 75, loses 25.  75W-25L = 50RP.
- It is not possible to go below 0 RP.
- There is no way to track your RP other than counting your wins and losses.

Comment: I was just going to answer and say that there is no evidence at all that this is the case. You seem to be right, great find!